# How to get timestamp of ib_insync real-time price tick?

Tags: tws, ib-insync

I want to combine real-time and historical data with ib_insync for analysis.
I cannot find something similar to IB EWrapper tickPrice callback.

Ib_insync:

(1)How to get millisecond data?
(2)How to get the time-stamp of each price in (1)?
(3)As real-time price needs to be concatenated with historical price of previous 3 days, is the timestamp of (2) compatible with historical price timestamp?

Thank you.